# Displaying and iterating a list within a string?

Tags: python, list

So I'm writing a program which part of it involves sending out an email.

Within the email body (which is a string), I want to display a list. However, I want to know how/or what the best way to do this because right now, it only displays the first element of the list (naturally). As you can see, the list I'm trying to put in at the bottom is:

```
formatted_times
```

Here's the code below:

```
FROM = gmail_user
    TO = ['mcgoga12@wfu.edu']
    SUBJECT = "StudyBug - Study Rooms for %s" % newdate
    TEXT = """
This is an automated email from StudyBug.

We wanted to let you know that the following studyrooms were booked for %s:

%s

Thank You, 

StudyBug 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Check out the project page!: https://github.com/g12mcgov/StudyBug

""" % (newdate, formatted_times)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [join](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list on newlines (or commas, or whatever you like) as you format it:

```
"""…booked for %s:

%s

Thank You, …""" % (newdate, "\n".join(formatted_times))
```

Comment: This works great in stripping the "['']" from the list, however, I want to completely iterate through the entire list. This will only print the first element

Comment: @carbon_ghost Is `formatted_times` a flat list containing only strings? or is it nested, or does it contain things that are not strings?

Comment: No, it's a flat list containing only strings.

Comment: @carbon_ghost then `gluestring.join` will list every item in the list.

Comment: hmm... Can't find anything regarding a gluestring.join? Care to elaborate more?

Comment: @carbon_ghost open a terminal, type `python`, then type `help(''.join)`. Or just [look here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)